# Email Attachment in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to attach an attachment in email using

```
 $attachments = array("http://localhost/sitename/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/uploads/Bluehills_10.jpg");
   $headers = "From: $from <$from>" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Disposition-Notification-To: $from\r\n";
   $mail_sent = wp_mail("$to", "$subject", "$msg", $headers, $attachments );
```

Using this code I am able to send an email to the correct location but the attachment is not getting sent along with the email.

Could anyone tell me what could be the reason.

Also I later I want to send multiple files as attachment. But the files wont be in zip format.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used an `url` as `file/attachment` path but you should use machine's path, you have this:

```
// A url (should be a path of your server)
array("http://localhost/sitename/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/uploads/Bluehills_10.jpg");
```

But, you should use server's path and it could be a relative path like `/uploads/images/photo1.jpg`.

Comment: thank you.. I had to give the server's path and not the http url.